# How to transform YYYYDDD to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, julian-date

I have a date which is given in YYYYDDD format, where YYYY is the year and DDD the days through the year (001-365).

Does the library from moment.js or any other library has a conversor for this kind of given dates to a modern date, like DD-MM-YYYY or something similar?

Comment: What did you try? There are tons of questions on how to change format X to Y.

Comment: Yes, `moment.js` can parse this. You can also just use a simple regular expression `/^(\d{4})(\d{3}$/`

Comment: Simply have a look at momentjs [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and show your attempts before posting a question, anyway something like `moment("2023005", "YYYYDDD").format("DD-MM-YYYY")` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the moment-documentation: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```js
// Parse string in format YYYYDD
let momentdate = moment('2023050', "YYYYDDD");

// Convert to format DD-MM-YYYY
let datestring = momentdate.format("DD-MM-YYYY");

console.log(datestring);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```